# nighwatchjs screenshots on_error vs on_failure

Tags: selenium, terminology, nightwatch.js

Can someone explain the difference between on_error and on_failure for screenshot generation in nightwatchjs?  The explanation below isn't clear to me what the difference is.

From http://nightwatchjs.org/guide:

> screenshots   object  none    Selenium generates screenshots when command errors occur. With on_failure set to true, also generates screenshots for failing or erroring tests. These are saved on the disk.
>
> Since v0.7.5 you can disable screenshots for command errors by setting "on_error" to false.
>
> Example:
>
> "screenshots" : {
>     "enabled" : true,
>     "on_failure" : true,
>     "on_error" : false,
>     "path" : ""
>   }

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the code of version 1.0.19 of Nightwatch.

**on_failure** is at the end of a test, if test assertions failed.

**on_error** is when an error occurs while executing a command.